# Is it possible that get likes count each facebook pages(not my page)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to gather each facebook pages's total likes.
Not for posts, just page likes.
Is there any access token or some method for getting the information that I want?

I tried this using facebook graph api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/{page's name ex: uniqlo.kr}/likes
```

and I get the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "A1LR4IU7npAvTZdHHn-zD_J"
  }
}
```

I think maybe 'uniqlo.kr' is not to be page-id

How can I get page-id that isn't mine?

Comment: The error message already told you to check the documentation, did it not? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: I already knew about this error, but I want to know is this the only way to get page public content access.

Comment: Yes. If you do not have admin access to a page, then you need public access.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I prepare to get public access.